# React Native: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'RNPermissionsModule' could not be found

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-permissions

I have a react-native app with expo. when i install react-native-permissions its giving me this error:

```
Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'RNPermissionsModule' could not be found. Verify that a module by this name is registered in the native binary., js engine: hermes
```

**Any Idea on how to fix this? What is the error means?**

Ive tried, pod install, reset cache, downgrade version to 2.0.3.

Here is my package json:

```
{
  "name": xxx,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "dev": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "test": "jest --watchAll",
    "prebuild": "expo prebuild"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/checkbox": "^0.5.16",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
    "@rnmapbox/maps": "^10.0.10-rc.0",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "expo": "~48.0.18",
    "expo-camera": "~13.2.1",
    "expo-checkbox": "~2.3.1",
    "expo-dev-client": "~2.2.1",
    "expo-font": "~11.1.1",
    "expo-image": "~1.0.1",
    "expo-linking": "~4.0.1",
    "expo-location": "~15.1.1",
    "expo-router": "^1.0.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.18.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "expo-system-ui": "~2.2.1",
    "expo-web-browser": "~12.1.1",
    "nativewind": "^2.0.11",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.8",
    "react-native-auth0": "^2.17.4",
    "react-native-camera": "^4.2.1",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.9.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^4.8.5",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.8.4",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.14.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.20.0",
    "react-native-vision-camera": "^2.15.6",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@types/react": "~18.0.27",
    "@types/react-native-auth0": "^2.17.4",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "jest-expo": "^48.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.2",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

- pod install
- downgrade version to 2.0.3
- reset cache
- yarn run ios

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error but with RNEncryptedStorage. The solution for me was simple, deleting the dev build on my device / emulator and install it again. If this doesn't work for you, try to build another development build.

Comment: What's the location of the dev build?

Answer (score 0):

I had RNDocument Picker, the below worked for me:

Remove the package to start with: npm remove react-native-document-picker Install version 8.0.0

`$ npm install react-native-document-picker@8.0.0`

You can also try:

`$ npx react-native-asset react-native-document-picker`

If you get an error saying react-natiuve.config.js not found create a new file with that name in the root folder and add this:

```
module.Exports = { project: {ios: {},android: {},},assets: ['./src/assets/fonts/'], // path of your assert file};
```

then `npm start -- --reset-cache`